While using dagger hilt for dependency injection for work manager, it is showing error -> Could not instantiate Worker Class
I am building a Calorie Tracker app. The functionality I want to implement with the WorkManager in my app is that after midnight the app reset's the completed nutritional information such as CompletedCalorie, CompletedProtein, CompletedCarbs and CompletedFat to zero. And I am using room to store meal information. I have set up a flag in the Meal entity, to specify that if a meal is completed or not, I also want that flag for each meal present in database should reset to false at midnight. So, I am using WorkManager to schedule a work in my app, and also using dagger hilt for dependency injection. WorkManager version is 2.9.1 and dagger hilt version is 2.46. The problem is that it is giving an error message telling that it could not instantiate worker class.
Error Message ->
Could not instantiate com.example.calorietracker.workmanager.ResetProgressWorker
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.calorietracker.workmanager.ResetProgressWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
    at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:94)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:243)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:144)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)


Could not create Worker com.example.calorietracker.workmanager.ResetProgressWorker

error message image
Code for Worker class is ->
@HiltWorker
class ResetProgressWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val mealDao: MealDao,
    private val preferencesRepo: PreferencesRepo
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                preferencesRepo.updateCompletedCalorie(0)
                preferencesRepo.updateCompletedProtein(0)
                preferencesRepo.updateCompletedCarbs(0)
                preferencesRepo.updateCompletedFat(0)

                mealDao.resetMealCompletionStatus()

                Result.success()
            } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                Log.d("ResetWorker", throwable.message.toString())
                Result.failure()
            }
        }
    }
}

Code for Application class is ->
@HiltAndroidApp
class CalorieTrackerApplication: Application() {
    private lateinit var workManager: WorkManager

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        val resetWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ResetProgressWorker>(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setInitialDelay(calculateInitialDelay(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()

        workManager.enqueue(resetWork)
    }
    private fun calculateInitialDelay(): Long {
        val now = Calendar.getInstance()
        val midnight = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = now.timeInMillis
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

            if (now.after(this)) {
                add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)
            }
        }
        return midnight.timeInMillis - now.timeInMillis
    }
}

Code for app module is ->
// using dagger hilt to provide dependency injection
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    // function for providing data store preferences
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesDataStore(@ApplicationContext context: Context): DataStore<Preferences> {
        return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
            produceFile = {
                context.preferencesDataStoreFile("basicInfo")
            }
        )
    }

    // function for providing preferences repo
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesPreferencesRepo(dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>): PreferencesRepo {
        return PreferencesRepoImpl(dataStore)
    }

    // function for providing app database
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "meal_database"
        ).build()
    }

    // function for providing meal Dao
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesMealDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): MealDao {
        return appDatabase.mealDao()
    }

    // function for providing meal repo
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesMealRepo(mealDao: MealDao): MealRepo {
        return MealRepoImpl(mealDao)
    }
}

I have applied the solution provided in this question, but it doesn't seem to work and I am still getting the same error.
